# Get all suites using Qase.io API, including sub-suites

Tags: python, python-requests

I would like to use python and the Qase.io API to retrieve all the test suites of a particular project. However, when I use the code that the documentation uses, it doesn't retrieve the sub-suites. It counts all the suites just fine, but the actual "entities" part of the response doesn't include the sub-suites.

I tried the following code, which is in the API documentation.

```py
import requests

url = "https://api.qase.io/v1/suite/PROJECTID"  # yes, this was replaced with my actual project ID.

headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "Token": "API_KEY_HERE"  # yes, this was replaced with my actual API key.
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), indent=4))
```

And it returned the following:

```json
{
    "status": true,
    "result": {
        "total": 33,
        "filtered": 33,
        "count": 10,
        "entities": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "Home page",
                "description": null,
                "preconditions": null,
                "position": 1,
                "cases_count": 0,
                "parent_id": null,
                "created": "2023-09-26 04:15:35",
                "updated": "2023-09-26 04:24:57",
                "created_at": "2023-09-26T04:15:35+00:00",
                "updated_at": "2023-09-26T04:24:57+00:00"
            }, # all following suites were formatted like this too.
        ]
}
```

But the "entities" part only had 11 suites, which I noticed were the ones that WEREN'T sub-suites. I'm a but stumped now since the documentation for the API doesn't mention that this could even be an issue at all, and doesn't provide a way to actually retrieve all of the suites, including the sub-suites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it retrieves all the suites and subsuites since you recieve "total": 33. But there is a **"limit" parameter** sent with your request parameters set **by default to 10**, that's why you are recieving "count": 10 and you are seeing only 10 suites.

So, you should **increase the "limit"** parameter value to see all suites and subsuites in your project. For example (url = "https://api.qase.io/v1/suite/code?**limit=100**&offset=0")
Note : max value that limit can take is 100